# Adding notes to order items in restaurant POS

Tags: odoo-9

Is there a way to add special instructions or to add a note to restaurant POS orders, like select a pizza, and add a note saying 'no broccoli'?

Can't find an option to do that; there seems to be only one search result listing a module which does this for an older version on odoo, but I'm sure many people have such a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the 'orderline notes' in the 'Restaurant & Bar' section of the POS settings.  That does what I need.