# How to add POS Restaurant notes for every items into POS Restaurant reciept?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale, receipt

I manage to change the template for POS receipt on **/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/pos.xml** which lies within :

```xml
<t t-name="PosTicket">
```

But how to change the detail on PosTicket ?

```xml
  <t t-name="PosTicket">

  .....

    <t t-esc="orderline.get_product().display_name"/>
```

???

I need to add the notes under the orderline.get_product().display_name. What should I write so it can show the notes?

I tried to add

```xml
<t t-esc="orderline.get_note()" />
```

But it seems doesn't work... Anybody know how to fix this?

PS: 
I already read :

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-alter-the-pos-receipt-37199

[Odoo Point of Sale + Posbox : How to modify receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459989/odoo-point-of-sale-posbox-how-to-modify-receipt)

[Odoo Point of Sale + Posbox : How to modify receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459989/odoo-point-of-sale-posbox-how-to-modify-receipt/33460882#33460882)

[Adding notes to order items in restaurant POS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626643/adding-notes-to-order-items-in-restaurant-pos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found the answer my self. It's :

```
<t t-esc="orderline.get_note()" />
```

After modify the pos.xml, logout and re-login n it will do the job... :)